# Intercepting WM_ENDSESSION message

Tags: windows, winapi, system-shutdown

Is it possible to intercept WM_ENDSESSION message to prevent another application from receiving it?

I'd like to command that application to perform an additional action before Windows reboots or shuts down, and it's not possible to configure the application that way.

The application is screen recorder software, and it just throws away the video when Windows shuts down. I need to prevent that and save the video.

Comment: You don't have to block WM_ENDSESSION in case you need to perform cleanup. You simply have to register a reason string. This is explained under [Application Shutdown Changes in Windows Vista](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms700677.aspx).

Comment: @IInspector: if the blocking app is updated to do what you say, it is telling Windows to not allow shutdown immediately (but the user can still override that and force shutdown). Neither application will be notified that the user *tried* to shutdown while shutdown is being blocked (unless the user forces it), so the blocking app will not be able to inform the other app to save the video before allowing the shutdown to proceed.

Comment: @IInspectable: See RemyLebeau's comment, he's right.

Comment: Okay, ffmpeg correctly handles that message and saves video. No need to intercept.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to intercept WM_ENDSESSION message to prevent another application from receiving it?

Technically yes, using a message hook from `SetWindowsHookEx()`.  Depending on the hook used, you can sometimes modify (not discard) messages to look like another messages, such as `WM_NULL`.  However, in the case of `WM_ENDSESSION`, it is just a notification, not a request, so Windows is still going to continue shutting down no matter what applications do with that message.

> I'd like to command that application to perform an additional action before Windows reboots or shuts down, and it's not possible to configure the application that way.
>
> The application is screen recorder software, and it just throws away the video when Windows shuts down. I need to prevent that and save the video.

So, you don't actually want to avoid `WM_ENDSESSION`, you just want to delay the other app from processing it until after your action is performed first.

The best option would be to simply contact the recorder author and request a feature be added to save the video on system shutdown.

Beyond that, MSDN says the following:

[Application Shutdown Changes in Windows Vista](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms700677.aspx)

> By default, applications without any visible top-level windows will be given 5 seconds to handle WM_ENDSESSION before being terminated.
>
> If your application may need more than 5 seconds to complete its shutdown processing in response to WM_ENDSESSION, it should call ShutdownBlockReasonCreate() in its WM_QUERYENDSESSION handler, and promptly respond TRUE to WM_QUERYENDSESSION so as not to block shutdown. It should then perform all shutdown processing in its WM_ENDSESSION handler.
>
> This way, Windows will treat your application as if it had visible top-level windows and will give it 30 seconds to handle WM_ENDSESSION.

So, you could try using a message hook to intercept `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` and have it call `ShutdownBlockReasonCreate()` and return immediately, then intercept `WM_ENDSESSION` to invoke the video saving action and call `ShutdownBlockReasonDestroy()` when it is finished.  Assuming, of course, that the recorder is throwing the video away in reply to `WM_ENDSESSION` and not `WM_QUERYENDSESSION`.

See MSDN for more info about how these two messages are handled by Windows:

[Shutdown Changes for Windows Vista](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb394721.aspx)

Comment: should I do it in my process or inject the code to recorder's process?

Comment: Your app can call `SetWindowsHookEx()` to install a message hook, but the hook itself needs to be implemented in a DLL so it can be injected into the recorder's process. If the hook approach does not work out, you might have to actually inject some code into the recorder process (see `CreateRemoteThread()` and related functions) and have that code subclass the recorder's window directly to intercept the messages.